# Отображение html в окне ввода

Tags: php, html

Имеем файл index.php
В нем такой код

```
echo '<textarea 
name="msg">'.$news['text'].'
</textarea><br />
 <input type="submit" name="true"
 value="Изменить" />
</form></div>
 <div class="links">» 
<a href="'.$HOME.'/news/">Назад в новости</a>
</div>';
```

Как реализовать отображение html кода после публикации поста новости
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не понятна задача! Объясните нормально

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть конструкция $string = <<<EOD....EOD;
Всё, что находится внутри, никак не преобразуется, а  пишется в строку как есть. Например:

```
$string = <<<EOD

<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
  <body>
 <style type="text/css">
   TABLE {
    width:100%;
и т.д.

EOD;
echo $string;
```

Comment: Нужно не так, а по-другому вывести чтобы отображался в окне html, чтобы можно было применять в новостях заголовки h2h3...